# In PlayN, is there a cross-platform constant for something like max integer value?

Tags: gwt, playn

I've checked the [Platform class](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html), but don't see anything like that. I can obviously set my own constant, but I wondered if anything like this existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` should be it.

Comment: Good suggestion. Will accept answer as soon as I have chance to verify in HTML version.

Comment: It works. Verified in Java and HTML versions. Source here: [http://code.google.com/p/klenwell](http://code.google.com/p/klenwell/source/browse/trunk/projects/java/playndev/playndev/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/klenwell/playndev/core/PlaynDev.java?spec=svn297&r=297#46). Thanks.